# Same code showing different runtime on PC and online compiler

Tags: elixir, runtime

For an assignment in university, we had to compare the execution time of ordered lists and ordered trees. Random values are generated and these values are added to the list and the tree in an ordered manner.

When I run the module on my laptop I get these values:

- For List, size increases from 2^4 to 2^13.
  ```
  0 0 0 102 512 1126 3276 6656 32665 217804
  ```
- For Tree, size increases from 2^4 to 2^13.
  ```
  0 0 102 204 204 307 819 2355 3481 9625
  ```

I don't understand why I get 0s here and also why the values in the beginning seem weird like 102, 204. At first, I thought it was because of some rounding-off going on. But when I run this exact code on any online compiler I get, these values:

- For List, size increases from 2^4 to 2^13.
  ```
  3 6 37 119 409 1494 7032 25552 101005 395432
  ```
- For Tree, size increases from 2^4 to 2^13.
  ```
  6 11 34 76 126 391 857 2178 4481 9720
  ```

No 0 shows up here and the values seem very real. I can't seem to understand what is causing this. Is it because of my laptop?
I use a Dell Inspiron 3576 with 8gb ram and i5-8250U.

Comment: Could you share the exact code in question?  It's hard to guess at what may be going on here with only output numbers--we can't even tell the units of the numbers (that is seconds or milliseconds).

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Sorry about that, I have added the code now. The measurements are in ms.

Comment: `:timer.tc` returns the time in microseconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: @JhonPedroza Thanks for the correction, but how does it show 0 in one case and some value in another?

Comment: It's odd. Even doing `:timer.tc(fn -> 1 end)` returns 1 µs on my machine.